# How can we get only the max date for each ID and drop the rest of the records?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am making sure a date in a dataframe is an actual date (it comes to me as an object).

```
from datetime import datetime
df_ps['data_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ps['data_date'], errors='coerce')
print(df_ps['data_date'].dtype)
```

Now, I want to keep only rows with maximum dates and where IDs are duplicated. The ID field is titled 'location'.

I run the following code and I get 31299 rows. This is the starting number of rows.

```
df_ps.sort_values(['location', 'data_date']).drop_duplicates('location', keep='last')
print(df_ps.shape)
```

I run the following code and I get 18103 rows.

```
df_ps_final = df_ps.loc[df_ps.groupby('location').data_date.idxmax()]
print(df_ps_final.shape)
```

I run the following code and I get 17740 rows.

```
df_ps_final = df_ps[df_ps.groupby('location')['data_date'].transform('max') == df_ps['data_date']]
print(df_ps_final.shape)
```

I put the location and data_date in Excel, clicked 'Remove Duplicates' and I ended up with 11816 records. Maybe the Excel thing is doing something that I don't know about. Anyway, in Python, what is the best way to keep only the max date for each ID?

Comment: `df_ps.sort_values(['location', 'data_date']).drop_duplicates('location', keep='last')` ?, `drop_duplicates` on `location` instead of `data_date`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I just fixed it. I'm getting 3 different results with the 3 lines of code. Why would they be different? More importantly, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: what is `len(df_ps)` v/s `len(df_ps.sort_values(['location', 'data_date']).drop_duplicates('location', keep='last'))` v/s `len(df_ps['location'].unique())` ? Could you please post these?  this looks like what I would have done :)

Comment: 31299 & 7289 & 7289

Comment: So the solution in the comments and your edit worked :) only you may need to assign the sort values output `df_ps = df_ps.sort_values... ` which is missing from your sort values and drop duplicate command, you don't assign the results back

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much!!